# Calling a parent field in JSON within a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, object, json

I am probably missing something simple here but I feel it best to ask anyway.

I have the following code:

```
$newarray = json_decode($jsoncode);
$rad = 24;
foreach ($newarray->objname as $obj)
{
    echo "<map name='" . $mapname . "'>";
    echo "<area shape=\"circle\" coords='" . $obj->x . "," . $obj->y . "," . $rad . "' alt='" . $obj . "'>";
    echo '</map>';
}
```

coming from a manually created json string:

```
$jsoncode = '{"objname":{"Forest 1":{"x":120,"y":120},"Forest 2":{"x":434,"y":225}}}';
```

I am getting an error when trying to call the $obj variable to use within the foreach. Is there like something I have to add to make it show the name stored in the variable?

P.S. I have no problem with the rest of the code

Comment: In the future, if you are getting any errors - you should include them in your post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `foreach` syntax should be like this -

```
foreach ($array AS $key=>$object){ 
  ... 
}
```

So your code should look like this -

```
foreach ($newarray AS $objectName => $obj)
```

- `$objectName` is the index in `$newarray`.
- `$obj` is the actual element from the array.

---

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

The documentation has this to say about the syntax of the `foreach` statement -

> `foreach (array_expression as $value)`
>       `statement`
>    `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`
>       `statement`

Comment: so are you saying foreach ($newarray->objname AS $key=>$obj){

Comment: im impressed actually! that's explained even more! Half understanding functions and knowing how they work is easily beaten by fully understanding them. Thankyou, I will accept after this time limit thing. Actually just tested it and I did need the $newarray->objname still but the rest worked fine.